# Can't login on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I cannot login on WordPress all of the sudden, I tried reintalling WordPress, and the template. I also tried deativating plugins. Everything works except for the fact that I can't login.

If I use a wrong password it will notify me on that. If I use the correct one I get this page:

> The page isn’t working
>    is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Logs: http://prntscr.com/big4km

Htacces: http://prntscr.com/big8jm

Line 884:

```
$manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
```

Comment: You probably need to look into logs to see the reason of 500 error, then edit your post and add logs if issue is still unclear

Comment: I edited op, http://prntscr.com/big4km and thanks for your fast response

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-login-after-automatic-40-upgrade]

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of problems that can give http error 500, have you tried these options?

1. Check directory permissions, make sure wordpress, wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes are 755.
2. Try the solutions shown [HERE](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-error-wp-admin-only).

   - Add these lines in your .htaccess:

     ```
     AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
     AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
     ```
3. Increase php memory limit in your php.ini file.
4. If it didn't work yet check your .htaccess again, make sure everything is right.
5. Add logs and your .htaccess file your question.

Comment: Tried all your solutions, and the ones on the page u referred, Still no result. I added the logs and htacces (Tried all the suggested htacces and recreated the file). And many thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try turning off Mod Security?

I had a similar issue - sometimes I couldn't log in, when I could I subsequently couldn't post anything and it was related to Mod Security.  Unfortunately, amending .htaccess didn't work for me, nor did all of the other solutions about PHP memory or permissions, however within cPanel I had the option to turn of Mod Security per domain.  I did that and haven't had a problem since.  It's not ideal, but if it works for you it can be a temporary measure until you're able to work with your host to figure out why this has suddenly started happening.